# How can we write the product of $n$ cosines?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

We know that 
$$2\cos k _1 x \cdot\cos k_2x = \cos(k_1+k_2)x + \cos (k_1-k_2)x$$

How can we write the product of $n$ cosines?

$$4 \cos k _1 x \cdot\cos k_2x \cdot \cos k_3 x =\cos(k_1+k_2+k_3)x \\+\cos(-k_1+k_2+k_3)x +\cos(k_1-k_2+k_3)x \\+\cos(k_1+k_2-k_3)x $$

$$8 \cos k _1 x \cdot \cos k_2x\cos k_3 x\cdot \cos k_4x=\cos(k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4)x\\+\cos(-k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4)x+\cos(k_1-k_2+k_3+k_4)x\\+\cos(k_1+k_2-k_3+k_4)x+\cos(k_1+k_2+k_3-k_4)x\\+\cos(-k_1+k_2+k_3-k_4)x+\cos(k_1-k_2+k_3-k_4)x\\+\cos(k_1+k_2-k_3-k_4)x$$

$$2^n \cos k _1 x \cdot\cos k_2x\cdots  \cos k_n x=?$$

Comment: What makes you think there should be a simpler form?

Comment: I don't think that there will be a simpler form like for the case $n=2$. But is there a way to write it for a general $n$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/880754/8157)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you. But they don't discuss the idea of the product. They have only considered the integral.

Answer (score 3):

Using Euler formula for $\cos$,

$$P:=2^{n-1}\prod_{m=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{e^{ik_m}+e^{-ik_m}}{2}\right) \\ =\dfrac12\prod_{m=1}^{n}\left(e^{ik_m}+e^{-ik_m}\right)$$

$$=\dfrac12\sum e^{i s_1k_1+is_2k_2\cdots +i s_nk_n}=\dfrac12\sum_{s \in \{-1,1\}^n}e^{i \  s \bullet p}$$

where $s:=(s_1,s_2,\cdots s_n)=(\pm1,\pm1,\cdots \pm1) \in \{-1,1\}^n$.

where $\bullet$ is the symbol for dot product.

Pairing the terms associated with $s$ and $-s$:

$$P:=\dfrac12 \sum(e^{i \  s \bullet p}+e^{-i \  s \bullet p})= \sum \cos(s \bullet p)$$

where the previous sums are extended to all $s$ such that if $s \in \{-1,1\}^n$ has already been used, $-s$ will not be used, in conformity with the results obtained so far for $n=2,3,4.$

Comment: In general this will only lead to more terms and a more complicated formula to solve/evaluate. (It's not your fault of course, but I'm just saying that in most cases the original product is much easier to work with than this.)

Comment: That means there is no other way of writing this for the general case? Anyway Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean a more "compact description"...I don't see one. But the important thing is that we have in this way an "algorithmic description" of the set of combinations of $k_i$s, don't you think ?